# ASPNet5 SeriLog LogDebug not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, serilog

I have an ASP.Net5 web application with serilog configured. In my home controller I print a Warning, Error, Verbose and Debug message, however in my console only Warning, Error and Verbose messages appear. The debug message is missing My configuration is:

```
public class Startup
{
  public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
  {

      Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
      .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
      .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
      .WriteTo.RollingFile(Path.Combine(env.WebRootPath, "log-{Date}.txt"))
      .CreateLogger();
  }


  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
  {
      loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
  }

}
```

I consume the logger via dependency injection, see below:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
    {
      _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        _logger.LogWarning("Warning");
        _logger.LogVerbose("Verbose");
        _logger.LogDebug("Debug")
        _logger.LogError("Error");
        return View();
    }
}
```

My log window shows:

```
2016-04-13 12:41:24 [Warning] Warning
2016-04-13 12:41:24 [Debug] Verbose
2016-04-13 12:41:24 [Error] Error
```

There are other debug messages that relate to build in ASP.Net functions.

Can anyone please advise what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you also need to set `MinimumLevel` on the `loggerFactory`:

```
loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug;
```

(ASP.NET's and Serilogs debug/verbose levels are switched in RC1, this is being rectified by RC2.)

Comment: Thats confusing but indeed absolutely correct. I got it working by setting loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Debug; Thanks for the advice. Now to look into upgrading to RC2.

Comment: Great, glad to hear it helped.